# The namespace associated with the prefix 'diffgr' could not be resolved.in castor

Tags: java, xml, web-services, spring, soap

i am getting following xml

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <StateID>1073</StateID>
    <State>Ahmedabad</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity2" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <StateID>1051</StateID>
    <State>Amritsar</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity3" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="2">
    <StateID>1024</StateID>
    <State>Bangalore</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity4" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="3">
    <StateID>1074</StateID>
    <State>Bhopal</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity5" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="4">
    <StateID>1034</StateID>
    <State>Chandigarh</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity6" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="5">
    <StateID>1025</StateID>
    <State>Chennai</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity7" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="6">
    <StateID>1075</StateID>
    <State>Dehradun</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity8" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="7">
    <StateID>1001</StateID>
    <State>Delhi / NCR</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity9" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="8">
    <StateID>1062</StateID>
    <State>Gwalior</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity10" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="9">
    <StateID>1011</StateID>
    <State>Hyderabad</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity11" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="10">
    <StateID>1035</StateID>
    <State>Jaipur</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity12" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="11">
    <StateID>1063</StateID>
    <State>Jhansi</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity13" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="12">
    <StateID>1036</StateID>
    <State>Jodhpur</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity14" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="13">
    <StateID>1064</StateID>
    <State>Khajuraho</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity15" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="14">
    <StateID>1026</StateID>
    <State>Kolkata</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity16" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="15">
    <StateID>1072</StateID>
    <State>Ludhiana</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity17" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="16">
    <StateID>1010</StateID>
    <State>Mumbai</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity18" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="17">
    <StateID>1065</StateID>
    <State>Orchha</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity19" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="18">
    <StateID>1016</StateID>
    <State>Pune</State>
</FromCity>
<FromCity xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    diffgr:id="FromCity20" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    msdata:rowOrder="19">
    <StateID>1037</StateID>
    <State>Udaipur</State>
</FromCity>
</root>
```

and following is my mapping

```
<class name="pkg.SourceCityWheelzResponse">
    <description xmlns="">Default mapping for class
        GhraPayOrderRequest
    </description>
    <map-to xml="root" ns-prefix="diffgr"
        ns-uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
    <field name="fromCities" type="pkg.FromCity" collection="arraylist">
        <bind-xml name="root:FromCity" node="element"
            xmlns:root="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
    </field>

</class>
<class name="pkg.FromCity">
    <description xmlns="">Default mapping for class
        GhraPayOrderRequest
    </description>
    <map-to xml="FromCity" ns-prefix="diffgr"
        ns-uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />

    <field name="stateId" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="FromCity:StateID" node="element"
            xmlns:FromCity="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
    </field>
    <field name="state" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="FromCity:State" node="element"
            xmlns:FromCity="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
    </field>
</class>
```

but i am getting following error

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: Castor unmarshalling exception; nested exception is org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException: The namespace associated with the prefix 'diffgr' could not be resolved.
    at org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller.convertCastorException(CastorMarshaller.java:675)
    at org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller.unmarshalDomNode(CastorMarshaller.java:554)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalDomSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:307)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:125)
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This XML is odd at best... Have you tried moving the namespace declarations to the root element like so:

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <FromCity diffgr:id="FromCity1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <StateID>1073</StateID>
        <State>Ahmedabad</State>
    </FromCity>
</root>
```

In fact, you don't even need the extra `diffgr` namespace because its `URN` is the same as the one of the default namespace. Or is this a bug in your XML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify namespace schema in root tag:

```
<root xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" sql:mapping-schema="DiffGramSchema.xml">
```

See [DiffGram Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa257368%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for examples of XMLs.